# How do i change atributes in activity layout from a diferent class?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I have my main activity which handles the clicks in the navigation drawer. then it calls a different Java class to do the rest of the work. keeping the main code separate. Here is my Main activity code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    ViewFlipper flip_it; //flip tussen screens = flip_it
    DrawerLayout drawer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, 
drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, 
R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        flip_it = findViewById(R.id.vf);
        flip_it.animate();
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    }
```

and then the OnNavigationClickListeners with the intent to run the other Java Class

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.nav_rec) {
        flip_it.setDisplayedChild(2); //Recordings
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,list_recordings.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Now in my Java class i am calling i want to change stuff on the layout that was called on the main activity like change button text.

```
 TextView player_tema = findViewById(R.id.player_tema); //todo declare bo
                    player_tema.setText(recording.getTema());
                    Button playpause = findViewById(R.id.pauseplay);
                    playpause.setText(R.string.pause_button);
```

How would i be able to handle this, as the layout is still active in the foreground. I just need help on how to communicate to the current layout from the class that is currently running now.

Thanks

edit:

```
public RecyclerView getRecyclerView(){
        return recyclerView;
    }
```

added the getter in my main activity but now my RecyclerView is throwing a NullPointerException. Please see below how i am using my getter in the second class.

```
MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
main.getRecyclerView().addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
main.getRecyclerView().addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), main.getRecyclerView(), new ClickListener() {
```

Full code:

```
Main_Activity:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    ViewFlipper flip_it; 
    DrawerLayout drawer;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        flip_it = findViewById(R.id.vf);
        flip_it.animate();
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {  
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) { 
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        if (flip_it.getDisplayedChild() == 3) {
            flip_it.setDisplayedChild(2);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.nav_rec) {
            flip_it.setDisplayedChild(2); //Recordings
            recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            list_recordings lr = new list_recordings();

            lr.maak_die_lys_vir_al_die_recordings();
        }
        if (id == R.id.nav_qanda) {
            flip_it.setDisplayedChild(1);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        if (id == R.id.nav_news){
            flip_it.setDisplayedChild(4);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        return true;
    }
    //some getters and setters
    public RecyclerView getRecyclerView(){
        return recyclerView;
    }
}
```

and the full code for second class:

```
Second Class: 

public class list_recordings extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

    MyRecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter;
    private List<Recording> recordings = new ArrayList<>();
    ViewFlipper flip_it;

    public void maak_die_lys_vir_al_die_recordings() {

        mAdapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(recordings);//todo declare bo
        MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
        main.getRecyclerView().addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL)); // 
        main.getRecyclerView().addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), main.getRecyclerView(), new ClickListener() { 
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                Recording recording = recordings.get(position);
                if (recording.getCaID() == 0) {
                    toasty(); //tasty om te load more todo load more code skryf
                } else {
                    flip_it = findViewById(R.id.vf);
                    flip_it.setDisplayedChild(3);
                    TextView player_tema = findViewById(R.id.player_tema); /
                    player_tema.setText(recording.getTema()); 
                    Button playpause = findViewById(R.id.pauseplay); 
                    playpause.setText(R.string.pause_button); 
                }
            }

            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
            } 
        }));
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        main.getRecyclerView().setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        main.getRecyclerView().setAdapter(mAdapter);
        recordings.clear();

        add_item("Ds.Braam Smith", "Ons is hier Vandag", 2, 4, "1992.11.21");
        Collections.reverse(recordings); 
        add_item("n/a", "0", 0, 0, "0");        
    }
    public void toasty() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Loading more...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } 
    public void add_item(String dominie, String tema, int CaID, int preeknommer, String date) {
        Recording recording = new Recording(dominie, tema, CaID, preeknommer, date);
        recordings.add(recording);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain this better "Now in my Java class i am calling i want to change stuff on the layout that was called on the main activity like change button text." ?

Comment: Okay sorry, So basically my main activity is setting the content view. Then i am calling from the main activity a different class. i want to be able to change for example the button text from the second class i called.

Comment: You simple want to access suppose textView of main activity in second class ? so that you can change the text ?

Comment: basically yes but not just textview... i also want to add stuff to the recycler view

Comment: did you tried making it static ?

Comment: tried making a static?

Comment: I am very confused as to why it is so difficult

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171003/discussion-between-abubakker-moallim-and-jacques-celliers).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A simple solution would be you can simply define Your Views in your MainActivity.class as

```
static TextView textView
static RecyclerView recyclerview
```

So that you can access it like MainActivity.textView or MainActivity.recyclerview

But using Static variables will cause you memory leak.

So you can try this another approach.
You can create getter setters for you views.

Just define in your MainActivity

```
public getTextView(){
    return this.textView
}

public getRecyclerView(){
    return this.recyclerview
}
```

Later in your second class :

```
MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
TextView textView = mainActivity.getTextView();
```

Comment: `public` getters seems like a better option that having `static View`s

Comment: You can do that too. But to make him understand I answered for static

Comment: sure, but that will eventually leave him with more problams than it solved, which makes it a somewhat bad suggestion IMO.

Comment: I understand your concern. First let me check is it what he wants ? because his question isnt much clear. Later will update the answer with getters and setters

Comment: I am getting a null pointer exception on the recycler view. How can i fix this?

Comment: where have you defined recyclerview in mainactivity

Comment: Right at the top just before on create i have : RecyclerView recyclerView..... and then where i am flippng the view the next line. im declaring it to  be findviewby id

Comment: Update the complete the code with everything defined